# Extracting certain words from varying addresses in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, worksheet-function

[image: Excel File]

I need to sort out these addresses but there is a big problem at hand. For example, the first address:

> "B-41, Vashishth Marg, Shyam Nagar, Sodala, Sodala"

The problem here is "Shyam Nagar" and "Sodala" are two different locations/areas. How can i sort this out? I do know that the first area is the correct one. In the example above, the correct one would thus be "Shyam Nagar". What options do I have? I would really welcome all the recommendations and solutions.

Comment: Its not letting me add the image. Instead, they have let me add a link to it. Click on "Excel File" to access it.

Comment: Surely you can't do it with plain excel. You would need a professional tool which has a good database of geographic locations and can perform quite advanced operations, so I doubt you could find anything free. And even if you find it, how should it know, that "Shyam Nagar" is the correct one, not "Sodala"???

Comment: I've just been putting it manually but this will take a long time because there are 2700 entries. I have also tried the LEFT, MID and RIGHT functions. I did that for the first one, but then characters need to change - so i quickly realized that it wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. So Shyam Nagar is not in Sodala? That means your data is wrong. What do you expect Excel to do? Correct your data?

Comment: A manual but relatively speedy solution might be to use 'Text To Columns' first on Comma then Space and like that extend the original data to multiple columns. Then decide which part you wish to retain and which to throw and what to concatenate if needed and recreate a single column that's your intended 'Locality' to use

Comment: @teylyn: Exactly - but i am not in a position to correct my data. I'm not saying that the solution has to come from Excel.

Comment: @pat2015: That's a great idea. On it.

Comment: How many addresses do you have to process?